# Access localhost on iPad

Tags: ipad, macos, testing, vpn

I want to access my web application on iPad for local testing (http://myMachine_Name). But here is the problem;

1. I am having a local copy on my Windows machine with a Weblogic server running and the app server requires a VPN connection
2. Is there any way by which I can access http://myMachine_Name on the iPad , and given that my local machine would be connected to VPN.
3. Is there any iPad app which can help in testing..My main purpose is to have the fastest way to test any changes I make on the iPad and that I think would be to directly access http://myMachine_Name on the iPad Safari. But I do not know how.

*Note: By VPN, I mean it is connected to another network at a remote location. Also the iPad is connected to the internet via a Wifi connection on MAC which is on the same local network as my Windows machine..*

I think having VPN connectivity on the iPad might be an option, but I'll want to avoid that as that would require paying huge licensing fee.

Please let me know if I need to provide any other clarifications..

Thank you.

Comment: My answer was too short. so I added more detail below...

Answer (score 2):

To access the file via the iPad, your Windows computer must be running a web server, Apache or similar.

Once it is up and running, you have two options:

1. Configure your iPad to use VPN and connect to the remote network. From there, enter the Windows Computer's local network IP address into the iPad, and you should be able to view the pages if everything is correctly configured.
2. Portforward port 80 from the router to your Windows computer. This is most likely done through the router settings (the router that the Windows machine connects through). Then enter the public IP address of the Windows Computer's network into your iPad, and again, assuming correct configurations, you will be able to view the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below for iPhone and iPad configuration using Fiddler (windows).  It is a possible solution listed here on StackOverflow.  [Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)