# How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?

Tags: localhost

I'm currently working on a project and I would like to test it out on two laptops at home where one laptop connects to the localhost on the other. I am using XAMPP. How do I do this?

Answer (score 330, accepted):

That's definitely possible. We'll take a general case with Apache here.

Let's say you're a big Symfony2 fan and you would like to access your symfony website at `http://symfony.local/` from 4 different computers (the main one hosting your website, as well as a Mac, a Windows and a Linux distro connected (wireless or not) to the main computer.

### General Sketch:

[image]

---

<kbd>1</kbd>  **Set up a virtual host**:

You first need to set up a virtual host in your apache `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. On **XAMP**, you can find this file here: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`. On **MAMP**, you can find this file here: `Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. [This step](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/) prepares the Web server on your computer for handling `symfony.local` requests. You need to provide the name of the Virtual Host as well as the root/main folder of your website. To do this, add the following line at the end of that file. You need to change the `DocumentRoot` to wherever your main folder is. Here I have taken `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/` as the root of my website.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/"
    ServerName symfony.local
</VirtualHost>
```

<kbd>2</kbd>  **Configure your hosts file**:

For the client (your browser in that case) to understand what `symfony.local` really means, you need to edit the hosts file on your computer. Everytime you type an URL in your browser, your computer tries to understand what it means! `symfony.local` doesn't mean anything for a computer. So it will try to resolve the name `symfony.local` to an IP address. It will do this by first looking into the hosts file on your computer to see if he can match an IP address to what you typed in the address bar. If it can't, then it will ask **DNS servers**. The trick here is to append the following to your hosts file.

- On ***MAC***, this file is in `/private/etc/hosts`;
- On ***LINUX***, this file is in  `/etc/hosts`;
- On ***WINDOWS***, this file is in `\Windows\system32\private\etc\hosts`;
- On ***WINDOWS 7***, this file is in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`;
- On ***WINDOWS 10***, this file is in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`;

<kbd>Hosts file</kbd>

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
##
#...
127.0.0.1           symfony.local
```

From now on, everytime you type symfony.local on this computer, your computer will use the loopback interface to connect to symfony.local. It will understand that you want to work on localhost (127.0.0.1).

<kbd>3</kbd>  **Access `symfony.local` from an other computer**:

We finally arrive to your main question which is:

> How can I now access my website through an other computer?

Well this is now easy! We just need to tell the other computers how they could find `symfony.local`! How do we do this?

<kbd>3a</kbd>  **Get the IP address of the computer hosting the website**:

We first need to know the IP address on the computer that hosts the website (the one we've been working on since the very beginning). In the terminal, on **MAC** and **LINUX** type `ifconfig |grep inet`, on `WINDOWS` type `ipconfig`. Let's assume the IP address of this computer is **192.168.1.5**.

<kbd>3b</kbd>  **Edit the hosts file on the computer you are trying to access the website from.**:

Again, on ***MAC***, this file is in `/private/etc/hosts`; on ***LINUX***, in  `/etc/hosts`; and on ***WINDOWS***, in `\Windows\system32\private\etc\hosts` (if you're using ***WINDOWS 7***, this file is in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`).. The trick is now to use the IP address of the computer we are trying to access/talk to:

```
##
# Host Database
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
##
#...
192.168.1.5         symfony.local
```

<kbd>4</kbd> **Finally enjoy the results in your browser**

You can now go into your browser and type `http://symfony.local` to beautifully see your website on different computers! Note that you can apply the same strategy if you are a OSX user  to test your website on Internet Explorer via Virtual Box (if you don't want to use a Windows computer). This is beautifully explained in [Crafting Your Windows / IE Test Environment on OSX](http://www.studiobanks.com/blog/post/279/crafting-your-windows-ie-test-environment-on-osx-106).

---

## You can also access your localhost from mobile devices

You might wonder how to access your localhost website from a mobile device. In some cases, you won't be able to modify the hosts file (iPhone, iPad...) on your device (jailbreaking excluded).

Well, the solution then is to install a proxy server on the machine hosting the website and connect to that proxy from your iphone. It's actually very well explained in the following posts and is not that long to set up:

On a Mac, I would recommend: [Testing a Mac OS X web site using a local hostname on a mobile device](http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/): Using [SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/) as a proxy. It's a 100% free solution. Some people can also use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) as a proxy server but it's 50$.

On Linux, you can adapt the Mac OS way above by using [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as a proxy server.

On Windows, you can do that using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). The solution is described in the following post: [Monitoring iPhone traffic with Fiddler](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html)

---

## Edit 23/11/2017: Hey I don't want to modify my Hosts file

> @Dre. Any possible way to access the website from another computer by not
>   editing the host file manually? let's say I have 100 computers wanted
>   to access the website

This is an interesting question, and as it is related to the OP question, let me help.

You would have to do a change on your network so that every machine knows where your website is hosted. [Most everyday routers don't do that](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133043#133045) so you would have to run your own **DNS Server** on your network.

Let's pretend you have a router (192.168.1.1). This router has a DHCP server and allocates IP addresses to 100 machines on the network.

Now, let's say you have, same as above, on the same network, a machine at `192.168.1.5` which has your website. We will call that machine <kbd>[pompei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompei)</kbd>.

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME
pompei
```

Same as before, that machine <kbd>pompei</kbd> at `192.168.1.5` runs an **HTTP Server** which serves your website `symfony.local`.

For every machine to know that `symfony.local` is hosted on <kbd>pompei</kbd> we will now need a custom DNS Server on the network which knows where `symfony.local` is hosted. Devices on the network will then be able to resolve domain names served by <kbd>pompei</kbd> internally.

#### 3 simple steps.

<kbd>Step 1: DNS Server</kbd>

Set-up a DNS Server on your network. Let's have it on <kbd>pompei</kbd> for convenience and use something like [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

> Dnsmasq provides **Domain Name System (DNS) forwarder**, [...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnsmasq).

We want <kbd>pompei</kbd> to run DNSmasq to handle DNS requests `Hey, pompei, where is symfony.local` and respond `Hey, sure think, it is on 192.168.1.5 but don't take my word for it`.

Go ahead install dnsmasq, dnsmasq configuration file is typically in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` depending on your environment.

I personally use `no-resolv` and google servers `server=8.8.8.8 server=8.8.8.4`.

**Note:** ALWAYS restart DNSmasq if modifying /etc/hosts file as no changes will take effect otherwise.

<kbd>Step 2: Firewall</kbd>

To work, <kbd>pompei</kbd> needs to allow incoming and outgoing  'domain' packets, which are going from and to port 53. Of course! These are DNS packets and if <kbd>pompei</kbd> does not allow them, there is no way for your DNS server to be reached at all. Go ahead and open that port 53. On linux, you would classically use [`iptables`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/iptables) for this.

Sharing what I came up with but you will very likely have to dive into your firewall and understand everything well.

```
#
# Allow outbound DNS port 53
#
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

<kbd>Step 3: Router</kbd>

Tell your router that your dns server is on `192.168.1.5` now. Most of the time, you can just login into your router and change this manually very easily.

That's it, When you are on a machine and ask for `symfony.local`, it will ask your **DNS Server** where `symfony.local` is hosted, and as soon as it has received its answer from the DNS server, will then send the proper **HTTP request** to <kbd>pompei</kbd> on `192.168.1.5`.

I let you play with this and enjoy the ride. These 2 steps are the main guidelines, so you will have to debug and spend a few hours if this is the first time you do it. Let's say this is a bit more advanced networking, there are primary DNS Server, secondary DNS Servers, [etc.](https://webhostinggeeks.com/blog/understanding-the-difference-between-a-primary-and-secondary-dns-server/). Good luck!

Comment: Nice reply. I followed the last part until I got to "Monitoring iPhone traffic with Fiddler". It points to Fiddler homepage. This should be the link: http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/01/monitoring-iphone-web-traffic-with.html

Comment: I have modified host file but problem is that I also have IIS server running so my "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" is pointing to IIS server how can I replace it with xamp server?

Comment: Is there also any way to do this without having to add it to your own host file?

Comment: For Windows 10, the file is now in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: Thank you @Flair, I have updated the answer for Windows 10 users.

Comment: @Mick any possible way to access the website from another computer by not editing the `host` file manually? let's say I have 100 computers wanted to access the website

Comment: @Dre Yes, you would have to do a change on your network so that every machine knows where your website is hosted. I have added info at the end of the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 31):

For testing on both laptops on the same wireless and across the internet you could use a service like http://localhost.run/ or https://ngrok.com/

Comment: localhost.run worked like charm. My server was running on port 8000 and just changed the command line from 80 to 8000.

Comment: Wow! awsome... it really worked at single go... thanks @tommyvn

Comment: Way easier to set up NGROK than update the local hosts file.  +1

Comment: Easy solution for quick test

Comment: how to use localhost.run?

Answer (score 23):

Provided both machines are in the same workgroup, open `cmd.exe` on the machine you want to connect to, type `ipconfig`, and note the IP at the `IPv4 Address` line.

Then, on the machine you want to connect with, use

```sh
http://{the IP of the target machine}:{port number}
```

E.g `http://192.168.0.1:80` if your site runs on port 80.

That should do it.

Comment: This would work if port 80 is the port for the app (normally it is) but keep in mind we can could be using a different port. That'd mean http:// + the IP of the target machine + ":PORT_NUMBER"

Comment: This was the simple solution I was looking for. @Codrin Eugeniu: Please consider to incorporate the suggestion ":PORT_NUMBER" into your answer as mentioned by ggderas. For me this was needed as I connected via port 8088 using Apache Superset.

Answer (score 22):

On Mac OS X:

1. In terminal, run `ifconfig` to get the internal IP of your machine on its current network.  It may be something like `192.168.1.140` or `10.0.1.174`.
2. Start a server.  For example, `node server.js` may start a server on some port.
3. On your phone, visit the IP address (e.g. `192.168.1.140:3000`) and be sure to specify the port.

Comment: nice and simple, just in case if you have multiple ip addresses. choose one which starts with inet 192.

Answer (score 6):

This tool saved me a lot, since I have no Admin permission on my machine and already had nodejs installed. For some reason the configuration on my network does not give me access to other machines just pointing the IP on the browser.

```
# Using a local.dev vhost
$ browser-sync start --proxy

# Using a local.dev vhost with PORT
$ browser-sync start --proxy local.dev:8001

# Using a localhost address
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8001

# Using a localhost address in a sub-dir
$ browser-sync start --proxy localhost:8080/site1
```

http://www.browsersync.io/docs/command-line/

Comment: I run an a webapp on localhost:3000. I used `browser-sync start --proxy localhost:3000` in a separate shell. On another device which is connected to the network I type: `${computerIP}:3000` but I see nothing. I guess there is something more I should provide.

Answer (score 5):

it may be that your firewalls are preventing you from accessing the localhost's webserver.
Put the IP addresses of both of your computers' internet security antivirus network security as safe IP addresses if required.
How to find the IP address of your windows PC: Start > (Run) type in: cmd  (Enter)
(This opens the black box command prompt)
type in  ipconfig (Enter)
Let's say your Apache or IIS webserver is installed on your PC:  192.168.0.3
and you want to access your webserver with your laptop. (laptop's IP is 192.168.0.5)
On your PC you type in: http://localhost/ inside your Firefox or Internet Eplorer browser to access your data on your webserver.
On your laptop you type in http://192.168.0.3/ to access your webserver on your PC. 

For all these things to work you need have installed a webserver correctly (e.g. IIS, Apache, XAMP, WAMP etc).

If it does not work, try to ping your PC from your laptop:
Open up command propmt on your laptop: Start > cmd (Enter)
ping 192.168.1.3  (Enter)
If the pinging fails, then firewalls are blocking your connection or your network cabling is faulty. Restart your modem or network switch and your machines.
Close programs such as chat programs that are using your ports.
You can also try a diffrent port number:
http:192.168.0.3:80  or http:192.168.0.3:81 or any random number at the end

Comment: Thank tou @KarlosFontana - you just answered my question too. I was having trouble connecting my iPhone to a server that I wrote on the desktop. The iPhone was connected to my PC's WiFi. Your last line answered my question :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is a side note if one still can't access localhost from another devices after following through the step above. This might be due to the apache ports.conf has been configured to serve locally (127.0.0.1) and not to outside.

check the following, (for ubuntu apache2)

```
  $ cat /etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

if the following is set,

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

then change it back to default value

```
NameVirtualHost *:80  
Listen 80
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, use **ipconfig** to get the local IPv4 address, and then specify that under your Apache configuration file: **httpd.conf**, like:

```
Listen: 10.20.30.40:80
```

Restart your Apache server and test it from other computer on the network.