# Url of localhost in ajax call

Tags: ajax, localhost, jsonp

I have an ajax script on a remote server making to call to my local host which is running a django app:

```
           $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url: URLLOCALHOST
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function(){}
                }
            });
```

what goes in place of my URLLOCALHOST?

Comment: This post provides a broad context but does not ask a specific question. You should consider dividing this larger problem into smaller more specific component problems that can be expressed technically and ask each question directly.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to narrow it down to one technical question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer here:
[Access to a site on localhost from remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364406/access-to-a-site-on-localhost-from-remote)

Apparently local host cannot be accessed from another network without security issues.