# Connecting 2 computers together via Localhost

Tags: windows, localhost

I've set up a website on my localhost but I want to test out how multiple users will use the site, so I'd like to be able to connect another computer for this. I've looked at a number of tutorials including [How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network).  I have done steps 1 & 2 but step 3 doens't seem to be working. I'm running windows XP on my localhost machine and Windows 7 on the external computer and would really appreciate your help with this, thank you.

Comment: You could just use [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/).

Comment: Thanks @Blender but I'd rather just connect my 2 machines together at this stage. I might use localtunnel later but everything is set up here at the moment. I just can't get the secnd pc to connect, is there anything specific I have to do to allow the 2 to communicate with each other?

Comment: Are they on the same network? If not, does your router allow external connections?

Comment: I haven't set up a network and to be honest I actually doubt my router allows external connections. How would i set up a local network for this?