# connecting to mac localhost via windows computer sharing the same network

Tags: apache, localhost, ip-address, mamp, vhosts

I'm running MAMP on a mac computer, and can successfully access it from any mobile device (or another mac) via the local IP address, which I've verified via mac > preferences > network. I've added  a virtual host for MAMP, and added this host to my etc/hosts file, as referenced in this stack overflow post:

[How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

However, I can't access the IP or the vhost from a Windows 7 PC, even though it shares the same mobile network. I've gone in to the hosts file on windows, and added the Mac's IP address there, and tied it to the vhost name I created, but no luck. Anyone know if there is some sort of additional configuration that has to happen in Windows to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you edited the hosts file in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, it should normally work most of the time. If it doesn't, the only thing I can think off is that it it sometimes necessary **to reset and clear the cache in Windows 7.**

You can have a look at [Windows 7 refresh DNS](http://www.whatsmydns.net/articles/windows-7-refresh-dns.html) for guidance. There is a step by step post [here](http://www.whatsmydns.net/flush-dns.html).