# Change root folder for XAMP

Tags: php, xampp

I've got an XAMPP installation running great and I've configured my local machine to be accessed by other users via my IP address using this tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network).

However, when I navigate to this page I get the standard XAMP (horrible yellow and orange) homepage.

Where can I change my root directory for my website so I've got a folder called `oursite` within the `htdocs` folder of XAMPP which I'd like to load when a user navigates  to my page instead of redirecting to the `xampp` folder.

Comment: In your vhosts. Usually a file called httpd.conf

Comment: In my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file I've added the lines:

`<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/oursite/"
  ServerName myserver.name
 </VirtualHost>
`

But it still redirects to `xampp/`

Answer (score 0):

Just as explained in the [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network) you mentionned, in the file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`, you should have a VirtualHost definition like this one :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Just Change the line above so that DocumentRoot point to your "oursite" folder
  DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/oursite/"  
  ServerName Whatever.server.name.you.want
</VirtualHost>
```

Just Change the line above the previous comment so that DocumentRoot point to your "oursite" folder