# Can't configure virtualhosts for XAMPP+Symfony

Tags: php, apache, symfony, xampp

I keep trying to configure it so that the domain symfony.local would link to the app_dev.php, but I also keep getting forwarded to the xampp page.

My hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1 symfony.local
```

My httpd-vhost is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName symfony.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\testAS\web"
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php
   <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\testAS\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm using Windows 8. Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Restart apache? first thought, if that won't help look for apache process in Windows process manager "kill" it and start again

Comment: @waldek_c nope, already tried. Killed and rebooted, nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a fairly recent version of xampp?  There is a new directive "Require local" that popped up a few years ago.  I remember being stumped by it.

```
<Directory "C:/home/ahundiak/zayso2016/cerad3/web">
##  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require local     ## Add This
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.api.zayso.org
    DocumentRoot "C:/home/ahundiak/zayso2016/cerad3/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

I am not an expert on configuring this.  The above works for me using the Symfony 2 .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

may be it issue of your hosts file entry of symfony.local and local ip address or may between them only TAB(on keyboard) require ...

OR if above answer not work follow below

please follow this link [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network) it help you solve your issue of not show symfony project