# Using Laravel with Genymotion

Tags: android, laravel, wamp, genymotion

I can connect to 10.0.3.2 from my genymotion emulator browser, however, it shows the WAMP homepage.  How do I connect to Laravel homepage? (I want to access the routes.php file)

I can access the laravel homepage from my computer browser (localhost:8000).

Comment: You need to get your local ip (192.168....) through ifconfig and use this on Genymotion instead of localhost

Comment: Do you mean 192.168.. assigned to the virtual box? I have tried that and it just shows "webpage not available".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging up, I finally got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675025/access-to-laravel-5-app-locally-from-an-external-device/30675683#30675683).

Run Laravel application as - "php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0" and access it using 10.0.3.2:8000/

Answer (score 0):

Just connect as follows. Add laravel directory located in `htdocs` .

```
http://10.0.3.2/your_laravel_directory
```

Or Go to CMD and enter `ipconfig` and find ip address like `198.168.x.x`

In `linux` enter `ip adrr' and find ip address like`198.168.x.x

Then open your emulator and go to  `http://198.168.x.x/your_laravel_directory`

Comment: I had already tried using the vboxnet0 ip address (mentioned in the comment above), however, it still didn't work. Anyway, thank you but I have edited the question with the working solution I found.