# ios access localhost from real device

Tags: php, ios, laravel, localhost

I have a local php(Laravel) server. I can access the domain "mydomain.dev" from an simulator but it does not work when I try to access it from a real device. I have the app running with the device connected to the same wifi network but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you tried this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675025/access-to-laravel-5-app-locally-from-an-external-device

Comment: Please post you code it will be useful to recognize your question

Comment: Does the DNS server that your iOS device is connecting to know how to resolve `mydomain.dev` to the IP address of your local server? If not then you will need to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt/terminal
Type

windows   `ipconfig`

linux     `ifconfig -a` or `ip addr show`

write your IPv4 adress

**exemple** (windows)

[image]

Then Run your server  `php artisan serve` or whatever you are using (wamp/laragon or easyphp ..etc)

then go to your browser in  your phone and navigate to `mydomain.dev`

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use IP address instead of mydomain.dev. When running on a real device, it will search dns server to look up mydomain.dev. If the dns server can't recognize this url, your device can't open it.