# React Native Fetch request throwing "Network Request Failed" error in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, react-native

i trying to connect react native android application with Laravel Api. So i using a simple Api to testing whether the request were sent. When using POSTMAN it is working. But when i using emulator from android studio it throw the error of "Network Request Failed". What is the problems?

The API return json tested by POSTMAN:

```
{"result":"hello world"}
```

But in react native

[image]

This is my function

```
async onRegisterPressed() {
        let response= await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                    name:this.state.name,
                    email:this.state.email,
                    password:this.state.password,
                    password_confirmation:this.state.password_confirmation,

            })
        });

        let res= await response.json();

            console.log(res);


}
```

Comment: Try to open 127.0.0.0:8000 on your emulator's browser. is it working?

Comment: TypeError is thrown when a network error is encountered. Can you access the internet in the emulator?

Comment: @SagarKhatri is not working.

Comment: @D-reaper Yes the internet is connected in emulator

Comment: @masterhunter can you make a request to a random website and see if you get a response?

Comment: @D-reaper i uploaded to my server, its working. So i think is the localhost problems. I am using WAMP server. Any idea?

Comment: @masterhunter see my answer.

Comment: this answer resolved my problem => https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/10093769
I hope resolve your problem

Comment: this answer resolved my problem => [https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/10093769](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/10093769)
I hope resolve your problem

Comment: this answer resolved my error
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/10093769](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/10093769)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect that 127.0.0.1 will point to the emulator itself in your computer where the server is currently running. Try replacing 127.0.0.1 with 10.0.2.2 if you are on AVD or 10.0.3.2 if you are on Genymotion or with your computer's actual IP address.

Comment: Work fine with Computer's actual IP address.

Comment: Thanks @Mμ. this was the issue. After 4 hours of try and error you saved my day!