# Test Retrofit with a localhost Laravel api

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm trying to create an app that connects to a Laravel project api, how can I test this when the project is on my local computer? I currently have like 6 projects on my localhost right now, I differentiate them all on the vhosts.conf and hosts files on Windows and Xampp and access them on my browser with different domain names, (for example: blog.me, dev.inae.com, ...)

Is there a way I can still test it with my current setup?

Answer (score 1):

you can access your api with the localhost link , because if you use localhost in the mobile , it will refer you the phone it self , so to do the job you can use a free domain hosting , or you can access your api using the computer ip, try to map your local host to your pc ip, this will do the job 
check this link :

[Access to Laravel 5 app locally from an external device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675025/access-to-laravel-5-app-locally-from-an-external-device)