# How can I access my localhost from my physical Android device?

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, xampp

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

I am creating a flutter app and restful API with Laravel.
it is work on AVD with url = "10.0.2.2:8000".
and my browsers on computer url = "localhost:8000".
I turned off the firewall on windows 10.
I can access to Xampp dashboard from my phone's browser "192.168.1.8:80" , but it doesn't work with port 8000

[My computer Ip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZcX2.png)

[Xampp server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d3m3.png)

Comment: Try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/5192105

Comment: great it is work thanks a lot

Comment: Sure I shall post this as an answer for anyone who visits this in future.

Comment: you also use ngrok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

Just make sure that the port is free.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675683/5192105

Comment: It goes on to listen on default port `8000`.

Answer (score -1):

php artisan serve --host=you ip address

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide command-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the command and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?