# How to share laravel app in local network

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, easyphp

I have developed a laravel application and I want to share this application in my local network to be able to access to this app from any workstation connected to this network.

I'm using EasyPHP-Devserver-17 and the app is working correctly on the local machine (127.0.0.1/app/public). I have changed the phpserve file to add "Listen 10.0.102.2:8080" and once I add this to phpserve file I can access to this address "http://10.0.102.2:8080" from others workstation, but when I go to the laravel app I got this error message:

> Not Found

I changed the URL in the following files in the laravel app: **app.php**, **.env** and **livewire.php**, but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

hello maybe this link will serve you
[Access to Laravel 5 app locally from an external device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30675025/access-to-laravel-5-app-locally-from-an-external-device)

php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80

"0.0.0.0" is your ip server

The default port it will be listening to will be 8000 to avoid any conflicts, so you can now access the application from your phone via the IP address of your computer:

http://192.168.1.101:8000

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's working but the livewire doesn't work, I change the url in the livewire config file but still not working, also is there any possibility to run the app without php artisan serve ?

Comment: open yours ports 

Open the file eds-app-dashboard.php in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apachexxx
Line 18, add your port number :

example
$ports = array(80,8080,8000);