# I have a mysql database on my laptop. How could I connect to it when I am not using the Local computer?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

It may seem like a silly question but i've never given it any thought. For the past few months i've been building a database and only ever accessed it through my laptop ( which is what I think is called the local Host, but please correct me if I am wrong). Yesterday, intuitively I thought, what if I were away from my laptop but would really like to either access the data or amend some records, how would I be able to do it. Which is the reason for my question.

I know when I use it locally all I do is enter the database, username and password via python for example. So, what if I was at an internet cafe and wanted to pop in and access my database. How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow remote connection to mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention your ip address of your system with defined port in that way you can access your database anywhere

Answer (score 1):

[How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

Question was already asked. Go to the answer, very helpful information.

Comment: No I haven't (at least if I did I wasn't aware of it). I only have workbench right now!

Comment: Ok, I've just installed MySQL Server. I guess I will start there.