# how to access localhost website from diffrent computers other than hosted computer with local area connection

Tags: php, mysql, apache, localhost

I tried to open my website from other computer performing steps explained at

[How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

It working fine too. But at "step 3b" I need to do changes in host file for opening it and I don't want that I want website should open once url is given without making changes in other pc or want to restrict access by giving client ip in httpd-vhosts.conf. I want all computers to access website connect in local area network.

How can I do this?

I tried editing httpd-xampp.conf

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 \
        fc00::/7 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 \
        fe80::/10 169.254.0.0/16

    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

It's not working too...

Comment: If you acess via IP you don't need those changes

Answer (score 0):

**This may be help you.**

1. setup your pc with static ip address like 192.168.1.200
2. create server directory in your htdocs/www directory
3. and make that server directory share
4. change localhost port in your appache configuration file to 1234
5. restart xampp/wamp server.

   **now go to other system and hit this url: 192.168.1.200:1234/server/your-project**

**to set static ip**:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/

**To change localhost port**: [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)

Comment: from which file localhost port should be changed?