# Is it possible to show a localhost site in another pc on same network?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I have a PHP site project in my pc. I am using wampserver for localhost program. I want to show this site from another pc or android phone (Same network).But i faced with a problem like photo below;

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4bzP.png)

Comment: @Ima i am using wampserver. How can i make it ?

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network this link may help you

Comment: Try this: https://john-dugan.com/wamp-vhost-setup/

Answer (score -1):

#### The easy way

Use a localtunnel to share your website through a private tunnel to your localhost and now with no configuration you can see your localhost through your mobile app or wherever you want

Use *ngrok*

1. Download [ngrok](https://ngrok.com)
2. Run the following command

`./ngrok http yourlocalip:80`

3.- Use the url provided by ngrok

Comment: I couldnt run this command :(

Comment: Did you download and install ngrok?

Comment: I have downloaded it, it was a simple ngrok.exe, i clicked on it and typed your command.

Comment: and error like this "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"

Comment: Ahh of you are on windows you have to use like `ngrok.exe http ip:80` in your command line

Comment: I run program, i executed command and still gives forbidden error