# Apache couldn't be started. Setting up Virtual Hosts. MAMP

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup Virtual Hosts on my mac using MAMP but I was not able to run my apache.

I already did this before by following  [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network/15431636#15431636) but still my attempts are unsuccessful.

I'm running **OSX Yosemite** and **MAMP 4.5**

**Update 1:**

I tried running `sudo /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/apachectl start`

and it returns this

`(48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
 (48)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs`

**Update 2:**

I tried renaming `envvars_` and restarted the apache `sudo apachectl restart` still the apache is not running

---

#### Solved

Upon troubleshooting, what I did is `force quit` all the `httpd` processes on my activity monitor and restarted the mamp!!

Answer (score 0):

Another server is already using port 80. You need to change the port of one of them. A port, like 80, can be used once per IP address.

Peter