# Developing backend on computer and testing on real mobile device?

Tags: express, url, server, proxy, expo

I am developing a backend with some routes that I want to use in an iOS App (developing the app with Expo and react-native).
So during the development mode (both for the backend and for the app), the backend is served on `http://127.0.0.1:80/`, and it is working perfectly when the app is on the iOS Emulator, but when I start the app on a real device, then I can't connect to the backend using the same url.
What url should I use ? Or which setting do I miss ?
Here is the code I have for starting the server...

```
const app = require('./app');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 80);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Localhost won't work if you have two different devices. Instead try to connect both to the same wifi network and use the **ipv4** adress of you pc *(find with ipconfig in cmd)* instead of '127.0.0.1'. Provided that your firewall doesn't block the connection.

Comment: how can I tell express to use my ipv4 instead of 127.0.0.1 or localhost ? because I just tried : let say my ipv4 is 123.456.789.10, I wanted to access  `http://123.456.789.10:80/` but it doesn't exist...

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network

Comment: thanks, the article http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/ helped a lot in my case actually ! I'll write the detailed answer down in case anybody comes here looking for a quick solution

Comment: unfortunately, the solution I wrote below is not working for me : I work on a react-native project with Expo, and it is using my computer IP already (with port 19000) to launch the app on my iPhone, and if I configure the proxy with the port 80, the back-end is working but not the expo app anymore...

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Mukeyii I found the answer (for a Mac and an iPhone at least) on [this page](http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/)

Here are the steps :

1. On your Node app, you need to give the port and the ip you'll be listening the app, for example :

```
const app = require('./app'); // app is made with express.js
app.set('port', 80);
const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

Strangely, I wanted to put the `127.0.0.1` ip but it didn't work. `0.0.0.0` worked for me so I put that one.

2. On the `/private/etc/hosts` file, add the line `0.0.0.0    any.url.you.wish`, save and test on a browser on your computer that when you start your app (dev mode) and you type the url `any.url.you.wish`, you go on your app.
3. [Download SquidMan](http://squidman.net/squidman/index.html) and open it, let it install what it wants to install.
4. In SquidMan > Preferences, set the port in the General tab (for me: 80)
5. On the Client tab, set a new ip: the ip address of the iOS mobile device. To get it, you need to click on the `i` in front of your WiFi connected network.
6. On the Template tab, add a comment on the line `http_access deny to_localhost` and add these two lines :

```
# hosts file
hosts_file /private/etc/hosts
```

7. Save the Preferences and Start Squid
8. Get the IP Address of the Mac in System Preferences > Network
9. Configure the Proxy on the iPhone (port + ip) at the bottom of the same view described in 5.

That's it ! Read more infos in this url: http://egalo.com/2012/05/29/testing-mac-web-site-using-local-hostname-on-mobile-device/