# how to access localhost from another device on same wifi network?

Tags: networking, ip

I run tor service on my MacBook; it runs on 127.0.0.1, and with port 9501, how can I access that IP and port on another device on same wifi network?

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network#15431636

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)

Answer (score 0):

With your terminal type "ifconfig" or go to your network configuration->TCP/ip and check your Mac's current IP, ex. 10.0.0.8

In the other device (another computer or a cellphone) just use the URL 10.0.0.8:9501.