# Make **ALL** websites in Chrome stretch their content to actually fit the screen width (as in: remove all horizontal space on left/right of ALL pages)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, browser, responsive-design

## The issue

I'm seeing a lot of websites these days with unused or empty space taking up 1/3 or more of the horizontal width of web pages.

### What I'm looking for

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to remove or decrease the unused horizontal space on webpages. This occurs for many reasons but typically it's due to:

1. An HTML element that specifies the `max-width` CSS property.
2. An HTML element or one of it's classes is referenced in a `@media (max-width: <pixel-amount>)` query.

---

### Examples

#### Example 1

The absolute perfect example is https://stackoverflow.com 
Here is an image of what I see to be even more clear about the problem:
[image: stackoverflow.com webpage]

---

#### Example 2

Here is a stackoverflow example where I think it would be very helpful if I could read/see more of the accepted answer without having to scroll up/down constantly. 
  **The main content of the page (question/answer section) only takes up 34% of the pages width**  at 100% zoom in Chrome 92 when I am full screen with a 1920x1080 resolution. 
[Link to page in this example image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network)
[image: stackoverflow's question/answer page]

---

### What I've tried

Using the uBlock Origin browser extension I can block elements from appearing on a web page. Depending on how the sites HTML is structured, this occasionally yields the desired effect. It may be possible to block a specific elements CSS property with uBlock Origin (currently trying to figure out).

---

### Possible leads

The content width for many websites such as stackoverflow or stackexchange seems to stop increasing after a specified max-width media query. Or if an HTML element has the `max-width` CSS property set.

On stackoverflow.com, if I remove the class: `body>.container` `max-width` CSS property and do the same for the CSS selector: `#content`, this resolves the problem on stackoverflow but the changes are reset after reloading the page. I'm assuming solutions for other sites are probably very similar to this or require a change to a class that is referenced in a `@media (max-width: <pixel-amount>)` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can permanently modify CCS properties of any site using uBlock Origin.

Open uBlock's options and go to filters and add the following to make stackoverflows content not have a max width:

- `stackoverflow.com##.container:style(max-width: none !important)`
- `stackoverflow.com###content:style(max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important)`
  [image: What the filters tab should look like in uBlock]

Don't forget to hit Apply Changes in uBlock!

You would do the same for other sites except you probably will need to change the site and class/selector
Depending on your browser, the code might be a little different.

## The Result

[image: Proof that stackoverflow content fits screen width]

Answer (score -1):

Super helpful!

I had a similar issue with recent seekingalpha.com redesign only using 40-50% of my screen width, and this really helped.

- seekingalpha.com##.F-aZ.F-a2.F-aU.F-z:style(max-width: none !important)
- seekingalpha.com##.dr-qB:style(max-width: 80% !important)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).