# How to use Postman to send request to another PC's server?

Tags: postman, rest

I have an Rest Api created on my destination PC. I can make post request to localhost using postman from same PC. but I want to send a post request to the localhost of another machine. What steps do i have to take to achieve this?

Comment: Did you check this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network

Answer (score -1):

To do so, you need to have both pc on the same local network if you want to test locally.

Use the other PC's(where REST API is deployed) IP or hostname to hit the REST API request.